# Transform DataFrame to list of dictionaries where column name is a value of key:value pair

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a panda DataFrame as follow

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        A            |         B        |         C        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      abc            |         34       |         8        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      abc            |                  |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      abc            |         6        |         321      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to conver it to a list of dictionary like this:

```
[
  {
   name: "A", 
   value: "abc"
  },
  {
   name: "B", 
   value: 34
  },
  { 
   name: "C", 
   value: 8
  }
]
```

There are several way to do it with a lot of data manipulation but I am looking for one that is straightforward if it exists
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [[{'name':k, 'value':v} for k,v in x.items()] for x in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
```

This would probably work, not sure it is straightforward though.